# How to find and match cell information and display message in Excel?

Tags: excel, match, vba

I have two sheets in Excel:

```
Sheet 1 
Column A - String Data 
Column B - Numerical Data

Sheet 2
Column X - User input String Data
Column Y - User input Numerical Data
```

The user inputs data in column X and y, the program compares data in column A with X and B with Y.

```
Typical Example    
A       B   
Apple   100    
Apple   201    
Apple   203    
Mango   501    
Orange  203    
Pear    560    
Apple   205

X        Y   Check   
Apple   100  Exists    
Peach   235  Does not Exist    
Grape   203  Does not Exist    
Mango   501  Exists
```

Every time the data matches, the check column says it exists. 
What would be the best way of achieving this?

Please let me know if you need any more clarifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS to see if it exists:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,A1,Sheet1!B:B,B1)>0,"Exists","Does not Exist")
```

This compares the values in pairs, so both columns at the same row need to match.

[image]

If what is wanted instead is to compare the columns individually and return "Exists" if the values are found in their respective columns independent of each other then:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,A1)>0,COUNTIF(Sheet1!B:B,B1)>0),"Exists","Does not Exist")
```

Comment: The first formula looks at the pairs. Apple 501 will not match with Apple 101 and Mango 501, since they are not on the same row.  The second formula will return exists but the first will return not exists. @Blackbird2552

Comment: Once it works for you make sure you mark the answer as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: oops i accidentally deleted my comment. First time using stackoverflow, so apologies. Yes you are correct it does indeed compare the two side by side. Let me see if everything works ok in my spreadsheet. thank you!

Comment: If it works mark as correct, it is something only you can do.

Comment: Thanks Scott,

so i put in the code in my spread sheet, and even though i put in apple 501 it still shows it as exists, when i evaluate the formula the first count if is true since it returns >0, the second count if also returns true as it also returns >0 as 500 does exist in the column. I am not sure how to add my excel sheet to this conversation i would add it so you can see what is happening.

Comment: What is the exact formula you are using?  I do not get that.

Comment: @Blackbird2552 there should only be one COUNTIFS(), do not use the second formula.  Use the first.

Comment: That would be my bad, yes the first one did work for me. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in 3 column on sheet2 
1st column is the vlookup of x with A

```
                =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet2!X1,Sheet1!A:B,1,0),0)
```

2nd column is the vlookup of y with b

```
                =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet2!Y1,Sheet1!B:C,1,0),0)
```

3rd column is to check weither there was a null in the other column

```
                =IF(AND(Z1="",AA1=""),"NOT EXIST"," EXIST")
```

Comment: This compares each column individually, As mine compares in pairs.  It will be interesting as to which the OP wants.  Your third formula will always be FALSE as you are returning `0` and not `""` in your IFERRORS().

Comment: Scott is correct this does compare it individually, as such it will return exist even when the data is on different rows. I want it to compare the values in the rows in pairs.